# Sticky session for load balancing with multiple domains

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite, load-balancing

so here is the scenario, i have a couple of load balanced servers, with a bunch of domains pointing to the load balancer IP. The website shows a different skin depending on the domain it was accessed from (this works fine). To assure session with the load balancing i used sticky session, problem is from what i know (which is not much) i need to define the domain for the cookie, but we have multiple possible domains.. i define the cookie as following on each web server:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule .* - [CO=BALANCEID:balancer.lb1:.domain1.com]
```

since we have multiple domains, i thought i could add a rewrite rule for each domain and apache would deal with that, something like this:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule .* - [CO=BALANCEID:balancer.lb1:.domain1.com]
RewriteRule .* - [CO=BALANCEID:balancer.lb1:.domain2.com]
RewriteRule .* - [CO=BALANCEID:balancer.lb1:.domain3.com]
RewriteRule .* - [CO=BALANCEID:balancer.lb1:.domain4.com]
```

but as you probably have figured out by now, the sticky session works fine only for domain1.com, the first on the list.

Any idea how to tackle this?

EDIT:

I am now trying this approach:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_X_FORWARDED_HOST} ^(www\.)?domain1\.com/ [NC]
RewriteRule .* - [CO=BALANCEID:balancer.lb2:.domain1.com] [L]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_X_FORWARDED_HOST} ^(www\.)?domain2\.com/ [NC]
RewriteRule .* - [CO=BALANCEID:balancer.lb2:.domain2.com] [L]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_X_FORWARDED_HOST} ^(www\.)?domain3\.com/ [NC]
RewriteRule .* - [CO=BALANCEID:balancer.lb2:.domain3.com] [L]
```

but its not working at all, are those rules wrongly written or
that logic simply wont work?

PS: i also tried with HTTP_HOST instead of HTTP_X_FORWARDED_HOST but it had the same result.

Comment: do you really need sticky session, why not sharing sessions on the server side (database/NFS, etc)?

Comment: well i tried setting the session.save_path of the php.ini on both servers to some shared location on a NAS, but the sessions were not consistant, reloading the page would sometime show the user as logged and sometime as not logged.. what else should be done except the setting in php.ini?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So i've managed to make it work... the second approach was good, only the env var was not good and i also removed the trailing slash:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP:X-Forwarded-Host} ^(www\.)?domain1\.com [NC]
RewriteRule .* - [CO=BALANCEID:balancer.lb1:.domain1.com] [L]
RewriteCond %{HTTP:X-Forwarded-Host} ^(www\.)?domain2\.com [NC]
RewriteRule .* - [CO=BALANCEID:balancer.lb1:.domain2.com] [L]
```

Note that if u want to access that domain via PHP its:

```
$_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_HOST']
```

Maybe this will save some time to someone else ;)

thanks for the replies!

Comment: Thanks for this! It helped me to discover that you need to use %{HTTP:X-Forwarded-Host} in .htaccess or Apache conf instead of %{HTTP_X_FORWARDED_HOST}